# how to edit this EXT JS box

Tags: php, extjs

i have bought a PHP/EXT JS2 script fiew years ago and i need to update it . i would like to know how to edit this EXT JS BOX

i cannot post the full EXT JS code here since it kill my browser ,
i know about js editor like sencha  but the code look very strange strange

```
ex:tvar fileStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({\r\n//\t\t\t\t\)
```

http://pastebin.com/ktZZStMN

it call these js files from the php code

```
    echo " <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/lovcombo/css/Ext.ux.form.LovCombo.compressed.css?r=1\">\r\n <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/lovcombo/css/lovcombo.compressed.css\">\r\n <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/iconlovcombo/css/iconlovcombo.compressed.css\">\r\n\r\n <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/gridsearch/Ext.ux.grid.Search.compressed.js\"></script>\r\n <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/treesearch/Ext.ux.tree.Search.compressed.js\"></script>\r\n <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/checkcolumn/checkcolumn.compressed.js\"></script>\r\n <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/rowexpander/expander.compressed.js\"></script>\r\n <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/tabclosemenu/ux.tabclosemenu.js?r=2\"></script>\r\n <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/lovcombo/js/Ext.ux.form.LovCombo.compressed.js\">   </script>\r\n <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/iconlovcombo/js/Ext.ux.form.IconLovCombo.compressed.js\"></script>\r\n <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"";
    echo $settings["ext_path"];
    echo "/extensions/centerlayout/centerlayout.compressed.js\"></script>\r\n ";
    $includes = ob_get_clean();
    add_to_head($includes, false);
```

could you please tell me how i can edit this in visual mode (im a new to js)

thanks you very much

Comment: *SO* is for ***specific*** programming problems - There are plenty of other resources online dedicated to teaching.

Comment: What do you mean by visual mode ? Why not start editing in your favorite text editor ? Notepad or ed would do it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that it is escaped with backslashes, in order to use it in php in a double quoted string. Read your file and save it again using php like this, in order to get a regular javascript file :

```
$js = file_get_contents('strangefile.js');
eval('$js = "' . $js . '";');
file_put_contents('newfile.js', $js);
```

About editing in visual mode : 
Sencha Architect allows you to edit the UI in design mode. I never used it so I cannot tell more.

Comment: thx you Lorenz , im gonna do this for "decipher" it   & yes i edit with notepad++ but i would like to edit visualy the box in design mode